# Please help with requestTopic in ROS XMLRPC Slave API

Tags: ros, xmlrpc, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible somebody who has a functional UDP Subscriber implemented can perform a Wireshark trace on the XML in the XMLRPC call and post it as the answer to this question?

It will help me out greatly, as I will be able to cross reference what my client is sending vs what is supposed to be sent.

My Java client calls requestTopic by passing in an array of String Protocol names (I am aware the ROS Java client does not support UDPROS, this is a different client). If I pass in using TCPROS, followed by UDPROS, then XMLRPC returns correct protocol information on TCPROS the default protocol. If I reverse the order, or only specify UDPROS, ROS returns an Unknown Error message. I've traced it back to a ROS cpp method called requestTopicCallback (or something like that, I was debugging this morning, and may be off on the exact method name).

All help will be appreciated!

Sincerely,

Aaron

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172724/please-help-with-requesttopic-in-ros-xmlrpc-slave-api/) by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4485/unknown_entity1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2014-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only UDP client that I'm aware of is roscpp. You should be able to run the unreliable node from the tutorials package and capture the output you're looking for yourself:

```
rosrun roscpp_tutorials listener_unreliable
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4485/unknown_entity1/) on 2014-06-04**:
Thank you ahendrix! That is exactly what I needed!

Aaron

**Comment by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4485/unknown_entity1/) on 2014-06-04**:
I spoke to soon. The stack trace shows that requestTopic is passing in TCPROS as the protocol. I wonder why the UDPROS example is running TCPROS?

POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: XMLRPC++ 0.7
Host: thyatira:46487
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-length: 302

requestTopic
/rosout/rosoutTCPROS